# How can I verify a node is deallocated in a C++ Linked List?

Tags: c++, xcode, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have Xcode and I would like to know how I can verify if my nodes were correctly deleted/deallocated. I am sure I'm going about it in the wrong way.

What I'm doing is printing data off of whatever ptrDel is pointing at, then use Delete to free it, and checking to see if I can view it again (and Yes, I still can). I thought this block of memory would be "zeroed" out or filled with something that doesn't have the old data. Why is it still possible to view what's there? Shouldn't I get a "bad memory access" error from XCode?

Here's my struct

```
struct Node {
  int data; 
Node* next;
 };
```

.......

```
bool deleteNode(Node **head, Node *ptrDel) {
     Node *cur = *head;

    printf("deleteNode top %d \n", ptrDel->data); //"deleteNode top a" would be the output for example


   if(ptrDel == *head) {
     *head = cur->next;
     delete ptrDel;
     printf("deleteNode 2 %d \n", ptrDel->data);  //"deleteNode top a" would be the output
     return true;
   }  

   while(cur) {
    if(cur->next == ptrDel) {
        cur->next = ptrDel->next;
        delete ptrDel;
        printf("deleteNode 2 %d \n", ptrDel->data); //"deleteNode top a" would be the output
        return true;
     }
     cur = cur->next;
   }


return false;
}
```

How else can I delete a node? I don't want my suddenly unlinked node from my first Linked list to be floating around in the system. What if there was important sensitive information in that node? Shouldn't it be filled up with some other data and placed back into free memory?

Thank you.

Comment: Memory is usually not cleared when it is freed, as this would be inefficient and is unnecessary in a well-formed program. Referencing freed memory is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Memory that has been freed with `delete` is typically not changed at all. You could do something like `ptrDel->next = NULL` after you have unlinked it, to avoid it producing a valid chain later.

There is no direct way, other than code-review by someone that understands the code, to ensure that your code is correct - of course, a set of good tests is also useful to ensure your code works (you can for example insert a number of elements, delete some of them and see if you can "search" in your list for them - they should be there before the delete, and not after), and you can create long lists and delete again (several thousand items and several thousand times over), and ensure that your overall memory usage isn't going up between the first and the last iteration of the outer loop.

Tools such as Valgrind can also be used to identify where/if you are leaking memory.